# Add new campaign member to existing campaign using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, campaign-member

I'm trying to add new campaign member in SF using ampscript in a landing page I built. Something is wrong with code as it's isn't working and Error 500 is displayed. Please see code attached below:

```
SET @ID = CreateSalesforceObject("CampaignMember", 3,
"CampaignId", @CampaignID,
"LeadOrContactId", @subscriberID,
  "Status", "Sent")
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you show how you set the @CampaignID and @subscriberID? does it work when you hardcode the Campaign ID and Subscriber ID?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `LeadOrContactId` by `ContactId` or `LeadId` depending on to whom you need to create the campaignMember.

This example will work if you need to create your campaignMember for a Contact on Sales/Service Cloud:

```
SET @ID = CreateSalesforceObject("CampaignMember", 3,
"CampaignId", @CampaignID,
"ContactId", @subscriberID,
  "Status", "Sent")
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend Rachid's answer, you can use the following in case you anticipate that both Leads and Contacts might enter your CloudPage. In that case, both will be processed correctly:

```
%%[
SET @subscriberID = _subscriberkey
SET @CampaignID = ""

IF NOT EMPTY(@subscriberID) THEN
        IF Substring(@subscriberID, 1,3) == "00Q" THEN
            /* Lead */
            SET @ID = CreateSalesforceObject("CampaignMember", 3,
            "CampaignId", @CampaignID,
            "LeadId", @subscriberID,
            "Status", "Sent")            
        ELSE
            /* Contact */
            SET @ID = CreateSalesforceObject("CampaignMember", 3,
            "CampaignId", @CampaignID,
            "ContactId", @subscriberID,
            "Status", "Sent")
        ENDIF 
ENDIF
]%%
```

In above, you need to set the `@CampaignID`.

If you're getting the 500 error, it's also possible that you're not testing correctly and the required parameters, `@subscriberID` and `@CampaignID`, are not passed correctly to the CloudPage.
The best way to test a CloudPage like yours is to include a button or a [CloudPagesURL](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/) in an email, perform a [send preview against a known subscriber](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_perform_subscriber_preview_test_send.htm&type=5) and enter the page from an email.